# solr, when loading csv fields are converted to array

Tags: solr

i'm loading a simple csv into a solr core, using `post` cli

this is example csv:

```
v21,v22
v31,v33
```

this is the loading:

```
solr create -c test
post -c test example.csv
```

let's query: http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "v11":["v21"],
        "v12":["v22"],
        "id":"f91582c7-9cfa-48db-813e-05b672261186",
        "_version_":1566774492373450752},
      {
        "v11":["v31"],
        "v12":["v33"],
        "id":"540fc0c0-0036-4823-8db3-bbb8bb3fb170",
        "_version_":1566774492421685248}]
  }}
```

all csv fields are array into solr, `"v11":["v31"]`
what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check field declaration for "v11" , "v12" in schema file, you might have given `multivalue=true`. remove it or set to false.

`multiValued="false"`

example:

```
<field name="v11" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Comment: The default "schemaless" configuration has all fields defined as multiValued by default, so this is probably caused by a lack of configuration. The default configuration is now also administered through the SchemaAPI and not the schema.xml file by default (the schema.xml is only read on collection/core creation)